# How to discard superfluous parameters when calling a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

### Background

I'm working on a PyQt application and have added the following debug decorator:

```
def debug_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
        logging.debug(f"Calling {func.__name__}")
        ret_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        logging.debug(f"{func.__name__} returned {ret_val!r}")
        return ret_val
    return wrapper_func
```

Among other things, i use this for click handler functions, for example:

```
self.share_qpb = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Share")
self.share_qpb.clicked.connect(self.on_share_clicked)
[...]
@debug_decorator
def on_share_clicked(self):
```

If i run this code i get the following error when the share button is clicked:

```
TypeError: on_share_clicked() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

The reason for this is that the `clicked` signal in Qt/PyQt sends the checked state of the button ([documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked))

This is only an issue when i decorate functions with my debug decorator, not otherwise (i guess the extra argument is discarded somewhere)

### Question

**How can i make my debug decorator work without having to add a parameter for every `clicked` signal handler?**

(I'd like to find a solution which works both for cases when the arguments match and when there is one extra argument)

---

I'm running Python 3.8 and PyQt 5.15

Comment: What would you expect to happen when the decorated function/method is called directly (i.e. not via a connected signal)? Should it still discard the superfluous parameters, or raise an error as normal? If the latter, you would need to detect whether the decorated function/method was being called by a signal or not. This is not an easy thing to do in a completely general way, especially if the decorator has to work with arbitrary callables.

Comment: @ekhumoro I guess it would be okay to discard the parameters, if that makes finding a solution to the question easier

Comment: You can discard the extra parameters by doing `args = args[:func.__code__.co_argcount - 1]`. However, this will hide genuine bugs, so I obviously cannot recommend using it in a debugging tool. If there was a *general* way to detect that a slot had been triggered *directly* by a signal, a proper solution would be possible. But I'm pretty certain there is no reliable way to achieve that at present in either pyqt or pyside.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by checking to see if the number of arguments provided `len(args)` is more than the number of arguments that the decorated function accepts `func.__code__.co_argcount`

I also check if the name of the decorated function contains the string "clicked" since i have made a habit of having that as part of the name of my click handler functions. This has the advantage that if another decorated function is called with too many arguments we will (as usual) get an error

```
def debug_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
        logging.debug(f"=== {func.__name__} was called")

        func_arg_count_int = func.__code__.co_argcount
        func_name_str = func.__name__

        if len(args) > func_arg_count_int and "clicked" in func_name_str:  # <----
            args = args[:-1]

        ret_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        logging.debug(f"=== {func.__name__} returned {ret_val!r}")
        return ret_val
    return wrapper_func
```

Thank you to @ekhumoro for helping me out with this!